# Async validation react-final-form setTimeout

Tags: asynchronous, react-final-form

I am migrating from redux-form and I have issue with form, where I have async validation. This validation happens on change, but I want to do the asynchronous call only when users stops typing.

In redux-form I was using setTimeout, clearTimeout and throwing an error in async validation similar to [this](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/79677759d40e6cf9840dfece094cc5eb3d1b9d6e/examples/asyncChangeValidation/src/asyncValidate.js)

I have created example which I would expect to be working. The full example is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j79v1o3pmv).

```
const usernameAvailable = value => {
  if (!value) {
    return "Required";
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    return "Username taken!";
  }, 500);
};
```

`Required` works as expected if there is no value, but `Username taken!` is never shown as an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`validateOnBlur`](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#validateonblur-boolean)?

Comment: It is not as good as waiting for user to stop typing, but it is good enough